# google sites modal to follow tha page scroll

Tags: bootstrap-modal, google-sites

I am trying to add modal in my google site (I am a layman in webpage etc).
I have created a embedded page and added the following in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MWE</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script> parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].scrolling="no"; </script>-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:Roboto Light;font-size:40; color:#990000">Modal Design</h1> <p
        style="font-family:Roboto Light;font-size: 16px">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
    1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.
    </p>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <ul style="font-family:Roboto Light;font-size: 16px">
      <li>MWE <button type="button" style="color:#990000; border:none;"
                                              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"><i class="fa
                                                                                                     fa-external-link"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-family:Roboto
              Light;font-size:24px;color:#990000">MyModal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="font-family:Roboto Light;font-size:16px;">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
            Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
            printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, now the main page scrolls independently of this page (please see the screenshot[image])

I don't want the "Modal Design" (i.e. the embedded code) to scroll independently of the complete page. I want a complete page scroll (including the top banner etc), like a normal page like:

[image]

How can I get that?

(This is a mwe, so changing the selection area is not a solution I am looking for)